# \addcontentsline gives incorrect page number for full-page figure

Tags: table-of-contents

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \section{The first section}
    Lorem ipsum

    \newpage % <---
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My full-page figure}
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering \rule{2cm}{2cm}
        \caption{My figure caption}
    \end{figure*}
    \clearpage

    \section{The second section}
    Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

This gives me a TOC that looks like:

[image: Output TOC]

Even though **My full-page figure** is on page 3, not 4:

[image]

Curiously, if I replace the `\newpage` command marked `% <---` with a `\pagebreak` command, the output is **2, 2, 4** instead of **2, 4, 4**.

How do I remedy this?

Comment: your figure is floating but the `\addcontentsline` was not so with `\newpage` then it happens on the page before the figure and with `\pagebreak` it happens on the page after the figure so you get 2 and 4. It can only happen on page 3 if it is inside the figure as figures are the only thing on float pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the table of contents line on the page that has the figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \section{The first section}
    Lorem ipsum

    \newpage

    \begin{figure*}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My full-page figure}
        \centering \rule{2cm}{2cm}
        \caption{My figure caption}
    \end{figure*}
    \clearpage

    \section{The second section}
    Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, that seems to do the trick. Thank you!